# GetRegistrationsByTagAsync and determining which type

Tags: azure-notificationhub

I might be missing something, but I've registered various devices (ios and android) with a tag MemberId_100 where 100 is the member's id in the db.

I'd like to query them:

`Hub.GetRegistrationsByTagAsync("MemberId_100", 100)` to receive a specific member's registration.  What I can't figure out is how to determine what kind of registration it is (ios, android, etc) or should I register it as a tag?

Answer (score 0):

The `GetRegistrationsByTagAsync` method [returns a collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt587761.aspx) of [RegistrationDescription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.registrationdescription) objects. That's an abstract class that specific platform registration descriptions implement: [AppleRegistrationDescription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.appleregistrationdescription), [GcmRegistrationDescription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.gcmregistrationdescription) etc. That is one way to determine it.

I'll update the answer if I learn of other ones.

Comment: Try to cast it and see if it fails?